# Visual Studio runs slow at netbook 1.5Gz and 2Gb RAM

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, performance, visual-studio, cpu-speed

I have an HP netbook with the following parameters:
Model: HP Mini 110-3500
Processor: Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N550 @ 1.50GHz
Installed memory (RAM): 2,0 Gb
System type: 32-bit Operating System
System: Windows 7 Starter

Also I installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate with Resharper 6.
It runs very slow.. My other applications run normally. Most resources are consumed by Google Chrome and Studio. My task is local application development using C# and Windows Forms.
At my job place I have PC with faster processor and 8Gb RAM. So Studio runs on it normally with high speed..
Could you please help me with the following questions:
    Is there any method to run Visual studio faster on this netbook?) 
    Or should I adjust some settings of Studio?
    Or may be other products such as free Express Studio or Professional will run faster?
    Should I post here some additional information such as Windows Task manager screenshot?
    Can Resharper have an impact on speed of Studio?

---

Thanks to all for answering. The real reason is not in low memory and processor.
My HP mini exactly meets these requirements.
Mu another big laptop, HP with the same characteristics but not Mini (with big display) runs Studio very well.
So the misterious reason was in Mini )))

Comment: Looks like this could be migrated to SuperUser, but there is this question already there...might be of some help. - http://superuser.com/questions/169403/what-are-the-minimum-and-recommended-requirements-to-run-visiual-studio-2010

Comment: Buy some more memory. Off topic. Voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's likely that you'd be lots better off here without Resharper.  The Resharper minimum requirements are greater than your machine.

> Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo 2GHz
>   Memory: min. 2Gb, recommended 4Gb or higher

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/system_requirements.html

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [the Visual Studio Hardware requirements here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/ultimate/overview) you are nearly at the minimum. I suspect adding Resharper to this configuration doesn't help.

In my experience multiple cores (2 or 4) and 4 Gb memory are fine for small projects. For bigger projects the disk is important too (SSD will help a lot during start up and build)

Comment: Poster combines slow processor with little ram and slow disc AND adds a HEAVY tool (resharper) then wonders performane is bad. I run VS on a hexacore with 16gb and an SSD and it is fast ;)

Comment: No need for 16 Gb - its is crazy )

Answer (score 3):

Your machine is below the Visual Studio 2010 specs: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/ultimate/system-requirements

Resharper will also take a heavy toll. You are especially below the specs for Resharper: 
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/system_requirements.html

Consider turning off the Resharper's Intellisense and Code Inspector capabilities as these greatly impact the editor's performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try compress Visual Studio folder. Sometimes it helps, sometimes not, depends on CPU/HDD ratio, compressing content and tasks.